# How to capture images in portrait mode using swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have gone through Apple's AVCam model and I have implemented portrait mode in my camera app. But the problem is that the captured image won't be in the portrait mode instead the picture will be as taken by the normal camera. Later I found out that I can activate portrait mode by going to the editing part and selecting 'Portrait' option.
I want the picture to be saved in portrait mode. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you maybe provide us with some more context or a piece of code we can work of? Maybe there's something missing or wrong with your code.

Comment: @Tanya you can follow this tutorial for the depth photo. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/capturing_photos_with_depth

Comment: @chirag shah I have followed the same documentation, still the output is the same

Comment: @Craz1k0ek I have included photoOutput.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = photoOutput.isDepthDataDeliverySupported and photoOutput.isPortraitEffectsMatteDeliveryEnabled = photoOutput.isPortraitEffectsMatteDeliverySupported during session configuration. And also, before capturing image I have included, captureSettings.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = photoOutput.isDepthDataDeliverySupported and captureSettings.isPortraitEffectsMatteDeliveryEnabled = photoOutput.isPortraitEffectsMatteDeliverySupported

Comment: did you ever solve this problem? @TanyaRao

Answer (score -2):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MainCameraVC.orientationChanged(notification:)), name: Notification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
    }

    func orientationChanged(notification: Notification) {
        let deviceOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
        var angle: Double?

        switch deviceOrientation {
        case .portrait:
            angle = 0
            break
        case .portraitUpsideDown:
            angle = Double.pi
            break
        case .landscapeLeft:
            angle = Double.pi / 2
            break
        case .landscapeRight:
            angle = -Double.pi / 2
            break
        default:
            break
        }

        if let angle = angle {
            let transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(angle))

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.label.transform = transform
                self.button.transform = transform
                ...
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response. But my problem is not with the orientation. I want to capture a portrait image where the background will be blur